# PHP script on host times out before finished

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I spoke to the one.com support who said that their servers times out after 50 seconds.

The problem is, that it the script times out before it's finished. How can I make the script loop until it is finished?

This is my script:

```
    <?php

//$id = $_GET['id'];

//$content = file_get_contents("http://www.boligsiden.dk/salg/$id");

$con=mysqli_connect("danico.dk.mysql","danico_dk","password hidden","danico_dk");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM elements");

$int = 0;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if($int < 500 && $row['link'] != "," && $row['link'] != "") {

    $link = $row['link'];

    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.boligsiden.dk/salg/$link");

    preg_match('#"LatLng":{"Lat":(.*?),"Lng":#', $content, $match1);
    $lat = $match1[1];

  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td>" . $lat . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  $int = $int + 1;

    }

}

?>
```

The time limit can not be overwritten. The default value on one.com host is always 50 seconds.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123: there's actually a `$int = $int + 1` at the end of the if-statement. However, as there's no `else {break;}`it's largely irrelevant.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 ``$int=0;`` at first so ``if`` statement is entered, and inside that ``if`` there is an increment ``$int = $int + 1;`` (``$int++`` would do the same), so there's apparently no infinite looping.

Comment: @Andreas: The answers are right about `set_time_limit()` - but when you say one.com servers time out after 50 seconds does that mean it can't be overwritten?

Comment: Yes, it can't be overwritten.

Comment: How many iterations does this loop do? Maybe it can be transferred to a background task - that would be my normal approach for a page fetcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other answers said, you should use `set_time_limit( int $seconds_before_timeout )` but no need to put it in the loop:

`set_time_limit(0)` will **cut off any timing out** (except in safe mode).

You should add a caching system: once you've retried your data with `file_get_contents()`, you could save it to a local file (like `/cache/boligsiden/salg/$link.dat`) so next time, if the cache is recent (you decide what "recent" means), you'll get the local file instead of doing a long-time-consumming `http` request.

*One solution:*

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("danico.dk.mysql","danico_dk","password hidden","danico_dk");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    // else, script will continue...
    // You could use a throw new Exception(...) instead
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM elements WHERE `link`!=',' and `link`!='' LIMIT 500");
// Way easier to put the conditions on the query itself
// as your query is not reused anywhere else

set_time_limit(0);  // No timeout

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // No more if there since the query itself managed it faster
    $link = $row['link'];
    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.boligsiden.dk/salg/$link");
    preg_match('#"LatLng":{"Lat":(.*?),"Lng":#', $content, $match1);

    $lat = $match1[1];

    echo "<tr><td>$lat</td></tr>";
}

set_time_limit(30); // From now on, script will timeout again
// That line can be removed depending on what's coming next
// Aka if you still want the script to not timeout, remove that line
?>
```

`set_time_limit()` : http://php.net/set_time_limit

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time the script is allowed to run:

```
set_time_limit(300); // allow a maximum execution time of 5 minutes
```

**Warning**

This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.

**Warning**

Be careful with this option. Wrong usage can lead to scripts that never end. Putting in a definite time limit, at the top of your script is the safest way to go.